# What Buddhist materials describe how to increase the number of people with good Karma in a geographic area?

Tags: karma

In some of his books Lama Ole Nydahl claims that the prosperity of certain region is determined (among other things) by the Karma of people living there. That is, people in Switzerland (or Silicon Valley) have, on average, a better Karma than inhabitants of poor, war-torn countries.

Imagine that the latter want to improve the situation: Gradually (over several decades or even centuries) build up good Karma so that the life in those regions becomes better (turn Sierra Leone into an African Silicon Valley, for example). Also, there is plenty of evidence that economic measures alone often don't fight poverty effectively, so why not trying out a Buddhist approach to economic development?

I assume that there are some publicly available teachings on how the average Karma of a region can be improved.

What are they and where can I find them?

Comment: Deport people with bad karma away from the area, make some with good karma go there :)

Comment: @eudoxos The Communists tried that already :) Seriously, by deporting (or any other form of violence) the deporters gather bad Karma, so in this particular case the means must be as oble as the end.

Comment: This is a very good question and an important one, but I do not believe you will find your answer here. (I'll try to compose you something)

Comment: @YodaBytes Thanks. If you wish, you can send me an e-mail to dp(at)altruix(dot)co.

Answer (score 2):

Though not directly affecting karma, there is a [variation of Metta Meditation](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/buddharakkhita/wheel365.html#ch6) mentioned in the Visuddhi Magga that increases universal love and brotherhood. Though the object is *universal*, its obvious that nearer vicinities would be felt more profound an effect.

If there is one thing in this world that can influence peoples' *Karma*, it is meditation. *Karma* is nothing but the result of aeons of conditioning of the five aggregates, and only with insight (*pradnya*) can they be positively affected.

As a practical experiment, just arrange a series of group meditation sittings among the people of the geographic area you want to improvise. After each sitting, just feel the *metta* vibrations in the air!

Answer (score 2):

**That is, people in Switzerland (or Silicon Valley) have, on average, a better Karma than inhabitants of poor, war-torn countries**

You don't know how much karma people have (not even on average).Unless your a Buddha or something.And you can't judge people's happiness based on regions or material possesions.Silicon valley might seem like a heaven,but it's not for the person commiting suicide because a plastic surgery went wrong.That's their hell.What of a kind person living a contented life in sierra leone who dies a peaceful death that's his heaven.We experience the effects of our karmas **in our minds** not on what happens around us.If that was the case most monastics would be experiencing the fruits of their bad karmas since they have to give up everything.Great Ajahns weren't from switzerland and neither were great people who cultivated great qualities such as Nelson Mandela and the Dalai Lama who both came from war torn and oppressed regions.Happiness isn't based on material wealth.True happiness comes from being a good person and you can be a good person anywhere,not just switzerland or silicon valley.The region doesn't cause your good karma,the person does or more accurately your actions.